# Can Selectize's Tagging be used with textarea?

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I was trying to use Selectize's (http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) Tagging functionality with a textarea but it always replaces it with an <input type="text"/> element.

Is there any way I can use it with textarea?

**UPDATE**

It was just a misunderstanding. Later I found that selectize creates a virtual input text box which is actually a div element. Though it looks like a text input, it also work as textarea as well. So, pressing enter inside the input box is also allowed which creates a new line, exactly like a textarea element.